# How can we make the thickness of legends in PlotLegends follows the one in PlotStyle

Tags: plotting, legending

In this code, I assigned the same thickness for `PlotStyle`   and  `PlotLegends` but the out shows inconsistency between the thickness of the plot.

```
Plot[{Sin[x], Cos[x]}, {x, -5, 5}, Frame -> True, 
 ImageSize -> Automatic -> {140, 140}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Directive[Red, Thickness[0.03]], 
   Directive[Black, Thickness[0.01]]}, 
 PlotLegends -> 
  Placed[LineLegend[{Directive[Red, Thickness[0.03]], 
     Directive[Black, Thickness[0.01]]}, {"Y", "X"}, 
    Spacings -> {.2, .1}, LegendLayout -> {"Column", 1}, 
    LegendMarkerSize -> 18], Scaled[{0.83, 0.85}]]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can fix this by using `AbsoluteThickness`:

```
Plot[{Sin[x], Cos[x]}, {x, -5, 5}
 , Frame -> True
 , ImageSize -> Automatic -> {140, 140}
 , PlotStyle -> {Directive[Red, AbsoluteThickness[6]]
   , Directive[Black, AbsoluteThickness[2]]}
 , PlotLegends -> Placed[LineLegend[
    Automatic, {"Y", "X"}
    , Spacings -> {.1, .1}
    , LegendLayout -> {"Column", 1}
    , LegendMarkerSize -> 18]
   , Scaled[{0.83, 0.85}]
   ]
 ]
```

[image]